# Can I update from Lion Server to Mountain Lion Server through Remote Desktop?

Tags: macos, upgrade, osx-server, remote-desktop

I currently have a Lion Server providing DHCP for my network, and access that server exclusively through screen sharing over [Apple Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/). I would like to upgrade from Lion Server to Mountain Lion Server, but am concerned that at some point during the process — especially since the server provides the DHCP service for my network, including the machine from which I access the server — I will be unable to access the server using ARD.

Can I perform the upgrade process entirely over ARD, or do I need to dig up a keyboard and monitor and connect them to the server box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I think the answer is Yes if your server has an static IP, and your client is on the same network.

But that's in theory of course. For example, if both your computers are in a network without DHCP, they will assign themselves with an IP starting with 169.254., link-local IPs. Now, the computers know that each other exists, and can still connect to each other with that IP.

Now, the question is simple, you need to know what your server's IP is when the DHCP is gone, and no one can assign IP address to them. And since you won't know, put a static IP on, and it would work.

That's in theory again. But I've had situation like these, and it did work for me.

Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Yes, both the server and my machine have static IP addresses. The server has its IP address from elsewhere (a SOHO router). So basically, when the sever is gone for a bit, even though DHCP from the server is gone, and my machine no has some arbitrary IP address, the machine that's being upgraded will have its static IP and ARD will still be able to access it as usual?

Comment: I assume I also need to make sure that the SOHO is able to keep the network going without the Apple server box providing DHCP (i.e., that the SOHO is not limiting DHCP in a way that would throw my ARD machine off).

Comment: Answering your first answer, yes, you should still be able to access that server as usual. Second, I believe you don't need to do anything for the SOHO box.

Comment: This worked without a hitch. The only problem (as you know) is that the useful Server Administration app is gone, and we're no limited to the terrible UI provided by "Server". At least DHCP has been restored (though with a nearly impossible to use UI). Also, Firewall has vanished.

Comment: Actually, this ended up being a disaster. [The main function  for which I use Server in the first place is now failing.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/84263/4395)